# VBA: end of statement Error

Tags: vba, excel

Silly question but I don't understand this error so if someone can tell me why this is happening and how to fix it I'd appreciate it. I have a formula that works in the excel sheet. In VBA all I'm doing is going to put this formula in and fill it down to the last filled row in the adjacent column. 
The formula I have is as follows:

Compile error, Expected: end of statement  (It does this at "*FIG*" portion)

```
Range("C1").Formula = "=IF(B1="","",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*FIG*",B1)),"FIG", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" *SF* ",B1)),"SF",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" *AF* ",B1)),"AF&L", IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" * IB * ",B1)) ),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" * ASIA * ",B1)),"IBAsia","IBexA"))))))"       
        Range("C1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:C" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row))
```

Comment: When using quotes within a quoted string, all of the quotes need to be doubled up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using quotes within a quoted string, all of the quotes need to be doubled up except the 'wrapping' quotes. In the following I've doubled up the quotes and removed some spaces that my experience tells me that the VBE mistakenly inserts when trying to make sense of a bad string.

```
Dim lr As Long
With ActiveSheet
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(lr, 3))
        .Formula = "=IF(B1="""", """", " & _
            "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*FIG*"", B1)), ""FIG"", " & _
            "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*SF*"", B1)), ""SF"", " & _
            "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*AF*"", B1)), ""AF&L"",  " & _
            "IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*IB*"", B1))),  " & _
              "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*ASIA*"", B1)), ""IBAsia"", ""IBexA""))))))"
    End With
End With
```

The above produces the following formula in the [ActiveSheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)'s column C from row 1 to the extents of column B,

```
=IF(B1="", "", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*FIG*", B1)), "FIG", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*SF*", B1)), "SF", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*AF*", B1)), "AF&L",  IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*IB*", B1))),  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*ASIA*", B1)), "IBAsia", "IBexA"))))))
```

If that formula is correct, it might be able to be simplified but confirmation on the formula would be necessary before making any suggestions to that end.

Comment: thank you for that! It's always the small syntax nuisances that get you.